# LINQ to Entity : truncate table fails because of foreign key constraint

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

In my database, I have a parent table and a child table with foreign key pointing to the parent.. at some point I have to clear all rows from both tables.

I used the following code in Entity Framework:

```
using (MuseumDBEntities db = new MuseumDBEntities())
{
   db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table childTable");
   db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("truncate table parentTable");
}
```

I get an exception at the second truncate because of foreign key, although I am clearing child table first.

What should I do? Is there another way to delete all rows of both tables?

I don't know if a foreach loop over all rows is practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's SQL server's fault!

You have two ways to achieve your goal:

1. Drop the foreign keys, then truncate the table and then recreate the foreign key (*I **don't** recommend this solution because it is too much work and usually not worth it*)
2. Instead of `Truncate` use `Delete` (I usually use this method)

Your code will look like this:

```
using (MuseumDBEntities db = new MuseumDBEntities())
{
   db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from childTable");
   db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Delete from parentTable");
}
```

Since the two delete statements have no conditions (no `where` clause), all rows will be deleted from the tables.

Comment: Bear in mind that using delete is going to incur more resources on SQL Server; locks, delete each row at a time and update transaction log per record deletion, etc...

Comment: ....I should have said *other* resource requirements; as the truncate would need to have the FK dropped and recreated. But it might be a concern depending on how many rows and record sizes are involved.